# Accessing data from mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have the following **types of requests**.

```
server/controllerName/access_id/id/field/field_value/api_name
server/controllerName/access_id/id/field/field_value/field2/field_value/api_name
```

**Few field examples:**

```
1. start date and end date
2. user name
3. user group
```

**Mongo DB data format:**

Mongo DB stores user order details. Each order contains user detail[10 fields] and order details[30 fields]

API has to give by default last 30 days of orders if no date is mentioned.

**My question:**

How can I efficiently read this data from mongo db?

**What I am currently doing:**

I am parsing the `httprequest` and adding these fields to a `map`

```
{"name":"gibbs", "category":"vip"}
```

I have to get all the documents where these two fields are matching and return the documents in the following form.

```
{
 user: "gibbs",
 total_Result: 10,
 [
  {
   //order details items from doc 1
  }
  {
   //order details from doc2
  }
 ]
 }
```

I am querying mongo db as follows.

```
MongoCollection<Document> mongoEngCollection = mongoDbReader.getCollection();
        BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();

        //Forming query using request parameter. requestAttributes contains map of request parameters.
        for(Map.Entry<PathAttribute, PathValue<?>> entry : requestAttributes.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey().getName();
            obj.add(new BasicDBObject(key, entry.getValue().getRawValue()));
        }

        andQuery.put("$and", obj);

        //Queryng mongo db
        FindIterable<Document> documents = mongoEngCollection.find(andQuery);
```

Then I am iterating the documents and grouping the fields as the required format.

It is written using spring.

I am fine with schema changes, query changes, annotation methods as long as it is very fast and conceptually correct.

Please advise me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to use aggregation framework. Statically import all the methods of helper classes and use the below code.

Use of `BasicDBObject` is deprecated in newer 3.x driver api. You should use the new class `Document` for similar needs.

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.*;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.*;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;

MongoCollection<Document> mongoEngCollection = mongoDbReader.getCollection();

List<Bson> obj = new ArrayList<>();
//Forming query using request parameter. requestAttributes contains map of request parameters.
for(Map.Entry<PathAttribute, PathValue<?>> entry : requestAttributes.entrySet()) {
   String key = entry.getKey().getName();
   //Check if key is not date and set the start and end date
   obj.add(eq(key, entry.getValue().getRawValue()));
}

//Build aggregation stages
Bson match = match(and(obj));
Bson group = group(
              first("user", "$name"), 
              sum("total_results", 1), 
              push("results", "$$ROOT")
);
Bson projection = project(fields(excludeId()));

//Query Mongodb
List<Document> results = mongoEngCollection .aggregate(asList(match, group, projection)).into(new ArrayList<Document>());
```

More about aggregation here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/

Comment: Does Aggregation frameworks use MR? Is it costlier operation to do?

Comment: No. MR is expensive operation compare to aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using Projections and Lookups in MongoDB.
Apply self joins https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/
Limit what to bring https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

I hope you can figure out easily how to write the query.